# how to use json_encode for my output?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I want to json_encode two items. One of them is from my table in database and another is a value that is returned from a function.
I want this output:

```
{"status":-1,"message":"uuuuuuuuuuuuu"}
```

but I have this:

```
{"status":-1,"message":{"Message":"uuuuuuuuuuuuu"}}
```

my model:

```
public function show_message($id)
{
    $string = "select Message from tbl_message where tbl_message.MID=$id ";

    $msg = $this->db->query($string)->row();
    $t = $msg;
    return  $t;
}
```

my controller:

```
$array = array("status"=>$temp,"message"=>$res);
$output = json_encode($array);
die($output);
```

Comment: Either `$array = array("status"=>$temp,"message"=>$res['Message']);` or `$array = array("status"=>$temp,"message"=>$res->Message);`

Answer (score 0):

Your question unclear

You could try some thing like

```
public function show_message($id)
{
    $this->db->select('status, message');
    $this->db->from('tbl_message');
    $this->db->where('MID', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Json Controller Function

```
public function example() {
    $id = '1';

    $message = $this->model_name->show_message($id);

    echo json_encode($message);
}
```

View

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $(".load").click(function(e){
      $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url("controller/example");?>",
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(json){
            alert(json[message]);
            console.log(json);
        }
      });
   });
});
```